# The example of Kähler-Einstein metrics on $B^2$ with an isolated singularity

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, kahler-einstein-metric

Let $B^2\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ be the unit ball.

> Does there exist a Kähler-Einstein metric, which can be expressed explicitly, on $B^2$ such that it has one isolated singularity at the origin $(0,0)$?

Comment: Well, there exist Ricci-flat (and hence Einstein) Kähler metrics on $\mathbb{C}^2$ minus the origin that are singular as metrics on $\mathbb{C}^2$ but that extend smoothly to the blow-up of $\mathbb{C}^2$ at the origin.  Does that count?

Comment: I think it counts. Can the metric be expressed explicitly? Could you please show me the references about such a metric?